# Problema com uma class no css e html

Tags: html, css

Bom eu estou com um problema 
quando eu chamo o background no body{} ele aparece como está na img:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas quando eu uso o mesmo codigo css para uma div ou um section ela não aparece nada .

como nessa img :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom o codigo css em questão é esse;

```
.slidee
{
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(../../image/BannerWithText.png);
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

quando eu mudo de .slide para body{} aparece normal, mas o chamado da section class="slide" não aparece nada ..

codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Secure Elo Bosting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <header>
        <span id="button-menu" class="fa fa-bars"></span>

        <nav class="navegacion">
            <ul class="menu">
                <!-- TITULAR -->

                <!-- TITULAR -->

                <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home icon-menu"></span>Inicio</a></li>

                <li class="item-submenu" menu="1">
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-suitcase icon-menu"></span>Serviços</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">

                        <li class="go-back">Voltar</li>
                        <li><a href="#">MD10</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Elo Boosting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Duo Boosting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vitorias</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-envelope icon-menu"></span>Duvidas Frequentes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-tag icon-menu"></span>Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="slide">
<div class="slidee">
    </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Felipe, isso ocorre poque o body tem um tamanho em altura de todo o corpo da página, sendo assim você consegue visualizar a imagem. Já na class .slidee ela não tem um tamanho, dessa forma parece que não funciona, tenta setar um min-height na .slidee, algo assim:

*.slidee{
  min-height: 300px;
}*

Acredito que seja isso, tenta aí!

Comment: Você é o cara mano, vlw !!.

Comment: só uma duvida irmão vc tem conhecimento em php mysql e jscript?

Comment: Opa, que bom que deu certo!

Comment: Tenho um conhecimento básico das linguagens citadas Felipe, dentre elas acredito que MySQL por lidar com SQL seja meu forte

Comment: ahh pq eu tou querendo pagar para alguém para pdoer fazer um sistema para mim não faço ideia de qual linguagem pode ser usada, mas se vc tiver interesse me deixa um contato seu .

Comment: Podemos conversar sobre isso cara, vou te passar meus contatos:
**e-mail:** gustavo.gialim@gmail.com
**celular:** (14) 99720-8435

Answer (score 0):

Existem dois possíveis erros, "possíveis pois depende da sua intenção. 
1. Se no CSS você está querendo referenciar o ID que está em , você deve referenciar usando "#".
2. Caso você esteja querendo referenciar a class "slidee", observe que no HTML existem dois "ee" (slidee), então no css deve estar da mesma forma.

```css
.slidee
{
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(../../image/BannerWithText.png);
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Comment: A primeira parte eu não entendi mt bem, a segunda parte eu entendi e arrumei, mas continuou da mesma forma. A única maneira q aparece o background ou qualquer outra img é utilizando o chamado body{} se não for com o body não aparece e eu queria fazer um slide logo a baixo do menus .